# Got very odd shape after running program multiple times

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm writing a game using opengl4.5 and Visual Studio 2017. Under an accidental coincidence, I run my game multiple times continuously(in release mode, run it and close it, then run it again and close it again, repeat this way). After about five or six times, I got a very odd shape(or model).

**The normal model:**
[image]

**The odd shape I got:**
[image]

**That shape is very similar to my other tree model:**
[image]

I use the same code to render the house and these trees and many other staffs. But It seems that only the house behaves strangely.

**The rendering code:**

```
    glBindVertexArray(model->m_VAO);

    if (!model->m_backCulling) {
        MasterRenderer::DisableBackCulling();
    }

    for (const auto& mesh: model->m_mesh) {

        m_shader->setInts(m_uniformLocations.at("useDiffuseTexture"), mesh.UseDiffuseTexture);
        m_shader->setInts(m_uniformLocations.at("useSpecularTexture"), mesh.UseSpecularTexture);
        m_shader->setVec(m_uniformLocations.at("material.base_ambient"), mesh.BaseMaterial.Ambient);
        m_shader->setVec(m_uniformLocations.at("material.base_diffuse"), mesh.BaseMaterial.Diffuse);
        m_shader->setVec(m_uniformLocations.at("material.base_specular"), mesh.BaseMaterial.Specular);
        m_shader->setFloats(m_uniformLocations.at("material.shininess"), mesh.BaseMaterial.Shininess);

        // Bind appropriate textures
        std::vector<Texture> textures = mesh.Textures;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < textures.size(); i++)
        {
            if (textures[i].type == "texture_diffuse") {
                glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            }
            else {
                glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
            }
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i].id);
        }

        glDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES,
            mesh.NumIndices,
            GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
            (void*)(sizeof(unsigned int) * mesh.BaseIndex),
            mesh.BaseVertex);
    }

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    MasterRenderer::DisableBackCulling();
```

And in corresponding destructor, I also glDelete* my VAO and VBO.

Has someone encountered the same problem as me?

Comment: This could be caused by undefined behavior. If "accidentally" some uninitialized memory has a certain value everything seems to work fine, otherwise not. What about running in debugger. The VS fills (in debug mode) everything uninitialized with patterns. Though, in certain cases, exactly this hides missing initializations. I once made concerning experiences with uninitialized `bool`s - in debug, they always was `true`, in release they had random values. I needed a while to find the reason... ;-) Btw. heads up. My new OpenGL projects usually start with blank screen... ;-)

Comment: The other reason could be broken H/W or driver (but I don't believe so). To find this out, you could try to reproduce the issue on another computer.

Comment: If you have 2 GPUs - dedicated and integrated, try running in on the other one and see what happens. I also think this is undefined behaviour. Good debugger is RenderDoc, allows you to capture frames and see what glCalls, shaders, buffer were used to produce that image. Which might show wrong bound buffer or something.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your reply, these days I temporarily put this question aside. Actually, I guessed the same with you, It caused by "undefined behavior". But it's very difficult to find the place causing this problem, maybe it's just a simple variable, maybe it's the OpenGL stuff. so I will attempt to fix the problem carefully when I reconstruct the entire project in a few days. Then I'll try on another computer to detect the issue.

Comment: @Quimby Yes, I have 2 GPUs - a GTX 950M and an integrated one. Because I use OpenGL 4.5 and I'm in Windows, so I think it won't work in integrated GPU. But thanks for your suggestion about the debugger. To be honest, I never used any debugger for OpenGL. I'll try RenderDoc to find the problem.